このサイトでは質問に答えることと質問を改善することと、どちらが優先されるんですか？
FTPで誤ってCentOS7から削除したディレクトリを戻す方法について を見てふと思ったのですが、このサイトでは質問に答えることより、質問を改善する（という名目で小言を言う）ことに熱心なように見えます。それが SOja の方針なのでしょうか？
これを見た未登録な読者が、このサイトでは質問しても答えを教えてくれる人は一人もおらず、ただ小言をネチネチ言われるだけで何の解決も得られないと判断しそうです（というかオイラならそう判断します）となると、新規登録者とか増えるはずがなくて衰退するだけだと思うのですがどうでしょうか？　現に質問自体にはマイナス票がついていて、小言コメントにはプラス票がついていて、回答数は（オイラがこの文章書いている時点で）０件です。

ぶっちゃけた話をします。「コミュニティで決めた最低限のルールが守れないような人はこなくていいし、ルールが守れていない質問や回答はなくてもいい」と私は思っています。
上げられた質問の質問者はこのサイトの初心者ではありません。SOjaのルールはある程度知っているはずなのですが、一つの投稿で二つの質問をしていました。私は一つ目の質問にはすぐに答えられそうでしたが、二つ目の質問には答えがわからなかったため、回答できませんでした。なので、まずは質問を一つにするようにコメントしました。これは複数の質問があるため、回答が不完全になるために回答が躊躇してしまったという典型的事例になると思います。
質問に対して、クローズ票、コメント、マイナス投票、編集の機能があるのは、質問をより良くすることで、回答を得やすくなることです。この機能自体に反発する人も確かにいます。どのようなコメントであっても、それがどれだけ丁寧であったとしても、「強制されている」と感じている人もいます。そのような人はSOja自体があっていない人です。そのような人に無理してSOjaを使ってほしくないし、このコミュニティに参加してほしいとも思いません。もし、SOjaを見て、勝手にクローズされたり、コメントされたり、マイナス投票されたり、編集されたするのに何らかの圧力を感じるというのであれば、このサイトを使わないという選択をした方がお互い幸せです。
SOja以外にも日本語QAは存在しており、質問へのコメントも評価も何も付けることができない所や、クローズや編集の機能が無いところがあります。そういったサイトでは、SOjaよりも多くの質問がありますが、質が悪く、改善もされずに放置されている質問も多くあります(もちろん、良問もあります)。私は、質問者だけでは無く、読んだ人全ての人に役に立ったと思われるような回答を心がけていますが、そのような回答をするには質問にも一定の質が無いとできません。多くの質問から質の良い質問を探すことに疲れてしまった私は、SOja以外で回答することをやめています。
質問の質をより良くする方法として、SOjaの方法がベストであるとまでは言えませんが、質問の質をより良くするような現行の機能を単純になくせば、他のサイトのように質問の数や新規登録者は増えるかも知れません。その時は、私は日本語QAでの回答者を引退し、拙い英語で本家で頑張ってみるしか無いかなと思っています。

まとまりの無い文章になってしまいましたが、「質問の改善することと回答をすることと、どちらを優先すべきか」という質問への答えとしては、そもそもの前提が違っていて、「質問の質が一定以上で無いとそもそも回答できない」というのが私の思いです。
全ての人が私と同じ考えであるとは思いませんが、このような考えをしている人もいるという事も考慮いただければと思います。

ちょっとだけ補足です。コメントで何かを指摘されるような質問をすることが悪いと言うことではまったくありません。よくルールがわかっていなかったためにあまり質が良くなかった質問をしても全然構わないのです。ただ、そういった質問をした後に、コメントされたり、編集されたり、クローズされたり、マイナス投票されたりすること自体が嫌だと言う人、その内容に従いたくないと言う人はSOjaが全くあっていないと言うだけです。指摘をよく読んで、質問をより良くしようと努力する人は大歓迎です。質問も良くなれば、回答も得やすくなって、Win-Winになるはずなのです。私は、少しでも質問者がそのようになってほしいと思ってコメントなどをしていますし、実際に質問がより良くなったときは嬉しいものです。

オイラ的には、高品質な質問ができる人はそれをそのまま google なり chatgpt なりに投げて答えを得ることができるから、わざわざ人間相手に質問しなくても良いはず、と考えています。なのでこういう場を使う人は必然的に「質問の初心者」が多いのでしょう（元ネタ質問者氏がそうであるとは言いませんが）そういう意味で「高品質な質問でないと答える価値が無い」だとそもそも Q&A 系サイトにて回答側にまわるには不向きなのかもしれないっスよ？　まあコメントとか勝手編集とかが気に入らない人は SO 向きではないよね、あたりは強く同意。

@774RR 答える価値がないのではなく、私の能力不足で答えられないのです。エスパーみたいに、質問者の環境やエラーメッセージを予測しろとか私には無理です。あと、私としては、GoogleやChatGPTで聞いて答えが得られるような問題にはあまり興味が無いので、そういうので解決できるようなありきたりな問題は有っても無くてもどっちでもいいんじゃないかなと個人的には思っています。

raccyさんの見解は、close理由は　何ですか？ で触れた、Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand で「多少の砂を拒絶してでも、質問の質を高く保つ」と説明されている通りですね。

@sayuri 母数が十分に多い場合に限り、成り立つお話ですよね。今の SOja の流量だとその理は成立するか否か微妙な感じ。

@774RR あなたは今のSOjaの現状をみて、あまりにも質問が少ないと憂いて、もっと多くの質問が来るようにするにはどうしたら良いのかと常日頃考えているのですね？とても素晴らしいことです。SOjaに人が増えて、質問が多くなり、より活発になること自体は、多くの人が歓迎することでしょう。ただ、とにかく多ければ多いほど良いと考える人もいれば、一定の条件を満たした状態で無ければ多くなっても意味が無いと考える人もいます。その条件も人によってまちまちですし、どれが正しいとか、間違っているとか、そういう物でもありません。その条件があなたも私も他の人もみんな異なっていると言うだけです。質の悪い質問を呼ぶくらいなら別に増えなくてもいい、と考えている人もいることもご理解いただければと思います。

流量が増せばよい＝広告とかスパム増えてもよいとは考えていません。 SOja の流量が増えても増えなくてもオイラのお給金が増えたり減ったりしませんし、むしろどうでもいいです。ただ「スタックオーバーフローって敷居高いよね（マサカリ投げられちゃう）」ってのは何とかしたほうがよさそう、って思ってます。

初心者だからといって、サイトの基本的なルールに従わなくていいという理由にはならないですし、そういったことや回答に必要な情報が明らかに不足しているなら、それらを指摘されるのは仕方ないことだと思います。ただ、自分もある程度質問内容から推測可能なレベルなことを、重箱の隅つつくように細かく聞いたり指摘するようなコメントは好きではないですけど。

ヘルプ記事では両者に優劣の差を付けるような何かは無いでしょう。
 スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範

私たちの使命は、質の高い質問と回答のライブラリを構築することです。そして、優しさや協力、相互尊重に根ざした、全ての人が歓迎される安全なコミュニティでのコラボレーションを促進することです。

他にもこれらのヘルプ記事が言及しているでしょう。
ツアー
気持ちよく参加するために
コミュニティで大切にしたい価値観
ただし結局のところ何を重視してどのような行動をするかは参加者個々人の裁量であり、永遠のテーマでしょうね。
774RR さんのこの記事の右側に並べられた「関連する質問」の中にも同様の趣旨のものが2015年からあります。
参加の仕方は一様ではない： もっと大勢のユーザに書き込んでもらうには
建設的なコメントとはどういうものですか？
私も以下のようなMeta質問記事を出していて、折々の他のMeta記事にその方向での回答やコメントをしていますが、そうした方向への動きは出てきそうにないですね。
ヘルプセンター: マイナス投票 に関する記述の整合性・一貫性
ヘルプセンター:「マイナス投票する」のヘルプを見易い/見付け易い位置に
まあ定期的に注意喚起して、行動規範に書かれた「優しさや協力、相互尊重に根ざした、全ての人が歓迎される安全なコミュニティでのコラボレーションを促進する」方向でのコメント/回答/投票が行われるように自身の見直しを行いましょう、とするくらいでしょうか。

初質問に対して「てめーの質問の質が低いから書き直せやゴルァ」と読めちゃう（丁寧に書いてあってもそう読める）コメントという名の難癖っぽく見える何かがついて、しかもその横に「いいね」っぽいカウンタまでついていて数値が＋２とかなっていると、それは当該質問者から見て「優しさや協力」とは思わないでしょう、ってのがオイラの意図っス。コメント書く前にもうちょっと慎重になってもいいんでね？　ってことで。

@774RR さんの感じているところは私も分かっているつもりです。私も多数の改善指摘(要求?)コメントを行っていて、その内容だと回答するのが大変だろうなと思われる質問に対して、一応なるべく中立的かつ対象/内容を明確にして改善方法を示しているつもりです。逆に他の人のコメントより量や頻度が多くて引かれているかもしれません。短く端的な記述だと排除されているように見えやすいですが、その辺の匙加減が難しいですね。
